# Is there any way to use chrome extensions in a remote debugging session

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I use CEF to set up a remote debugging session, but since its not running in my Chrome's devtools themselves (but as an actual webpage), I don't have access to my react or redux dev tools extensions.

Comment: Try installing those extensions in the remote browser. Otherwise submit a feature request on https://crbug.com

Comment: The problem is that it runs inside of the frame rather than the brower's quote-on-quote 'native' dev tools.

Comment: The documentation says that the UI is webapp downloaded from the remote browser hence my suggestion above.